# Using Amazon FreeRTOS older versions to build demo applications

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, freertos

I want to use older versions of `Amazon FreeRTOS` and build the demo applications that the already provide by default. However, when I checked the [releases](https://github.com/aws/amazon-freertos/releases) I only get the source files belonging to a release when I download the `zip` file. I could not follow the latest user guide (as it is very different with older version - no `cmakefiles`, `cmakelist` files etc. in the older version folder) and neither I was able to find an older user guides to get started with older versions. Anybody know where to look in order to get started with developing using older versions? Big help. Thanks

Comment: I recommend you add more links to things you've downloaded and tried, end explain in more detail what you've tried, to improve the quality of your question and your likelihood of getting a good answer.

Comment: And in this particular case, if you haven't spent at least ***4 hrs*** researching this and trying it out on your own already, go do that now. You'll be much more informed and able to ask a good, solid question. If you find your own answer during that time, answer your own question and I'll be sure to upvote it.

Comment: I honestly don't know how to get started, when I used the newest version, I went through the starter guide, downloaded the `arm` toolchain, generated the build files using `cmake` and finally compiled the build files. By default, MQQT demo was selected and It was very easy for me to change the demo file that was required. Here, I don't have any `makefile` or anything to generate the build files and compile the program.I went through folders, neither i did find a readme file. I tried with version `1.2.7` `1.3.0` and I didn't find any document to get started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after hours of trying I think I found the reason. I think the older versions of `Amazon FreeRTOS` does not support `Cmake` as it does for the new versions. So, what could have done is to use the vendor specified IDE's to carry out the debug and uploading through the IDE itself. I tried using the specified method for the older versions and it does work correctly. The problem that I had was I never use IDE until now and was relying on `Cmake` and command line to build up the binary file which was harder (or may be impossible) with the older versions. Building with the IDE is similar to the way that was explained in the newest user guide.

Comment: Yes this is correct the team have recently added CMake support and for older versions this did not exist. Actually the IDE project files are being generated from the CMake build output, and CMake is not the primary build mechanism, although it is in your face because the files are in every folder. The primary build mechanism is still the IDE itself, even for the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

The older getting started guides are unfortunately not available online. If you can be more specific and indicate which project and which version you are trying to build and where you got stuck we will be able to help you resolve your problem.

You can also post for help at the AWS Developer forum site here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=276 as the team actively monitors that forum for requests for help. If you specify which version and which target platform you will be able to get help there quickly.

Comment: I tried with version 1.2.7 1.3.0. I wanted to build demo application (like MQTT), but I didn't find any make file or a way to generate the build files as I did with the newest version. In newest version with cmake I was able to generate the files and compile. I dont even find any cmake files inside the directory. I searched in the internet and could not find any hint to how to get started.

Comment: Yes this is correct because the older versions did not use CMake. Cmake was first added around June 2019